# SF Book about a primitive reservation from advanced civilization

Tags: story-identification

I recall this book from approximately 20 years ago, in English.  It was pretty young-adult-ish, but I recall it categorized in the SF/F wall of the library.

- The primary characters are two teenagers, boy and girl.
- She lives in a primitive farming society, isolated from the rest of
  the world because of a peace treaty of some sort.

  - I think it was her, not him.  I have confused myself on this trying to recollect details.
  - The peace treaty is because the more primitive society is less destructive of the earth.
- The boy contacts her by using a bee-drone to whisper things.  This is something that she has been long warned about because if you consent, they can remove you from the reservation.
- She plans to hitch a ride on a high-speed underground train.  The route bends near her house so it slows down enough to drop onto.

> - They discover that the primitive society's paper books have references to things missing from the modern society's history, such as the city of Prague.

> - They realize that it is not the farming society that is the preserve.  It is actually more destructive to the earth to farm like they do.  Instead it is the modern civilization that is the preserve from a singularity-ish civilization.

> - The world dissolves and the sun is all fragmented. They say something to the effect of "I guess they decided to stop waiting."

> - The book ends with them living in a post-human virtual? world with everything they could want.